# Multiple Manufacturers ID DB REPLACE - opencart 3.0.3.6

Tags: database, opencart

Can please someone help me with DATABASE code? SELECT * FROM `oc_manufacturer` WHERE 1
I have combined two opencart stores into 1, so I have now multiple manufacturers and different products are assigned to them from each store. Before I can delete the duplicates, I need to assign the right id to right products. So..

If manufacturer id is 11
And the same manufacturer is 57

How can I assign a right manufacturer to a products that have 57 id, but needs to be 11 now.
Can you send me the right code so I can run in SQL?

Comment: You need update oc_product table not oc_manufacturer. Manufacturers are assigned to the products in oc_product table. But if you not familiar with sql, better update your products using OC admin.

Comment: Yes I know I need to update product table. I have 2000 products it is not possible to manually change them. How can I run in SQL? Replacing product who have 11 to 57 id manufacturer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it on your own risk. **First make full backup of your DB**
Next ran this query in SQL edit in phpMyadmin:

```
UPDATE  `oc_product` SET manufacturer_id = 255 WHERE manufacturer_id = 5
```

Where in my example `255` is the new, or existing manufacturer_id which you need to assign to the product and `5` is the manufacturer_id which you later will delete/remove.